# Creating a Stream from a List to Build Cards

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm creating a Home Auto Application. I have several button datas stored inside my Database (Realtime Database). In my home page I created a StreamBuilder to listen to whenever there is a button created or any type of data that has entered or leaved.

I'm currently having problems with my StreamBuilder, I can't access the data from it on the main page, and when I try to print the snapshot.data, I get 0 as response. The Stream is a List.

This is the output from snapshot.value:

```
[{icon: delte, nome: Junior}, {icon: add, nome: Televisao}, {icon: bulb, nome: BAtata}]
```

This is the Stream:

```
Stream<List> readData() async*{
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> button_list = Map();
    var lst = [];

    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

    Stream stream = await databaseReference.child(user.uid+"/buttons/").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      final value = snapshot.value as Map;
      lst = value.values.toList();
      
    });

    await for(var event in stream) {
      yield event.lst;
    }
  }
```

I will be using the content from the list to create the buttons.
This is the create card page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreateCard extends StatelessWidget {

  String name;
  String icon;
  CreateCard(this.name, [this.icon]); //[] para que o icon não seja obrigatorio de colocar

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 10,
              left: 10,
              child: Icon(
                icon == null ? Icons.check_box_outline_blank : getIconData(icon),
                size: 35,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 95,
              left: 15,
              child: Text(name, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

IconData getIconData(String name) {
  switch (name) {
    case "Lock":
      return Icons.lock;
    case "LightBulb":
      return Icons.lightbulb_outline;
    case "Check":
      return Icons.check;
  }
}
```

This is the Home Screen:

```
import 'package:automacaoaplicativo/buttons/create_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:automacaoaplicativo/services/auth.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main page'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton.icon(onPressed: () {
            _auth.signOut();
          }, 
          icon: Icon(Icons.logout), 
          label: Text('Logout'))
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _auth.readData(),
        initialData: 0,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.hasError){
            return Container(color: Colors.red);
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.hasData){
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData || snapshot.hasData){
            return GridView.count(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: [
                CreateCard("ola"), // I would need to loop throw this card and 
send the data from readData() on the list format,
 CreateCard(snapshot.data[0][0], snapshot.data[0][1]) and so on for position 1, 2, etc
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async{
                    _auth.readData();
                  },
                    child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                    child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white,),
                    
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how the app is looking, there was supposed to be 3 of these black boxes since I have 3 data from buttons, If I had 4 there was supposed to be 4, and so on:
[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUdQD.png)

Comment: Inside your Stream function you need to emit the values of the stream. Basically use `yield` to emit the List you want available. I looks the stream you already have already created is what you want to use, so you need to use `yield* stream;` to emit that stream. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Apealed Hey, I have updated the question with what I tried. But I get this error:  if (argument == null) throw ArgumentError.notNull(name); ->
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s) (stream): Must not be null)

Comment: It is telling me that it is null for some reason

Comment: Try initializing your `var lst;` like `var lst = [];` to be empty and not `null`.

Comment: @Apealed I have made that right now, but I'm getting the same error:
`Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s) (stream): Must not be null)`

Comment: Then the stream object you are creating isn't yielding anything. Also you are awaiting that stream twice, which is a bit of an anti-pattern. Try fiddling around with those two parts of the Stream. Some where you aren't emitting a value from a stream. You function is kinda wonky in the ways I mentioned.  So try: creating the stream object (w/o the await), then do the await for-in loop. Also try checking the values being emitted an each step. I know that's a lot!

Comment: @Apealed Let me see if I got it, I should use a Stream<Object>. But the loop part I don't get how I'm suppose to work with. Since I will need to loop the data later on, like on a List or Map.

Comment: I got a bit lost on what I should try, could you format a answer please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try matching your stream design pattern to something like this:

```dart
void main() async {
  // This is where you would use a StreamBuilder rather than this use.
  await for (var value in getData()) {
    print(value);
  }
  
  /*
   * return StreamBuilder<List>(
   *  stream: getData(),
   *  builder: (context, snapshot) => YourWidget(snapshot.data);
   * );
   * */
}

// This is *your* Stream function.
Stream<List> getData() async* {
  var list = [];

  // Make sure the stream you are wrapping is invokable.
  await for (var data in mockRemoteData(10)) {
    // this is where you do you data manipulation.

    list.add(data);
    yield list;
  }
}

// Ignore the implmentation, just imagine you are recieving data from a network
// and it just timeouts at some point.
Stream<int> mockRemoteData(int timeout) async* {
  int i = 0;
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i++;
    if (i == timeout) break;
  }
}
```

`getData()` is the function you are trying to make. You are basically *wrapping* another Stream, in the example it is `mockRemoteData()`. Try matching your code to this pattern.

Comment: [Here's an extended example](https://dartpad.dev/651efae7457105f49e7766e9559c2652?) with a generic `Data` class.